# As an assassination rogue what is the best stat to buff with food currently?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

It seems like the best stat to buff for Assassination Rogues changes often, so what is the best one to buff currently?  With cooking, I can buff a stat by 90, but should it be Agility, Critical rating or Haste rating?

Thanks.

Comment: Hi there! The problem with answering questions concerning changing content is that the answers are only correct at a certain time and therefore only relevant to the people who stumble upon it during that time. As you mention yourself, the best stat to buff changes often, so as a result I'm voting to close this as too localized.

Comment: @mana While it's true that MMO content changes somewhat more often than most games, calling a question like this 'too localized' would be tantamount to simply swearing off MMO questions altogether. Any answer to this question is likely to be stable for quite a while, given current class design anyway, so I find it hard to call this localized.

Comment: Maybe change the question to include a version or patch number, or maybe create tags such as wow-v4.0, wow-v4.1 etc.

Comment: @LessPop. That's true. I was being rash. The main thing that set me off was the "currently". Currently means absolutely nothing to people in a year.

Comment: @Cory that problem leads to management issues and "wrong" answers persisting (despite the tagging difference).  A better solution would be to update the answer over time with information on what the change is and why.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Agility.

Agility is worth roughly *two times* as much as the next best stat for Assassination rogues.

Answer (score 2):

Before you can answer this question, there's one very important question to consider:

**Are you hit capped?**

Until you reach the cap, +hit is, bar none, *the* best DPS increasing stat. There have been a few mentions by blizzard designers that this is intentional.

**If you are not**, eat some [Grilled Dragon](http://www.wowhead.com/item=62662) if it's available.

Only after reaching the +hit cap should you start in on the +AGILITY of [Skewered Eels](http://www.wowhead.com/spell=88042) or [Seafood Feasts](http://www.wowhead.com/item=62290)

Comment: This is actually not true. Agility is more valuable to rogues than Hit as of now. This is actually pretty unlikely to change for a variety of reasons, not least of which being that the hit cap for rogues is so damned low. [More Info.](http://elitistjerks.com/f78/t110134-assassination_guide_cata/)

Comment: @Less -- I see where you're coming from, but the +Hit food is actually giving you three boosts on that chart -- melee +hit, yellow +hit, and spell +hit, which, combined, is more than the calculated EP of raw Agility. Or am I misreading the chart entirely?

Comment: You're misreading the chart. The three numbers refer to hit rating before each respective cap. Hit rating before the cap for Special Attacks, Hit rating before the spell hit cap, and hit rating before the melee attack cap. Each respective cap is higher than the last, and each 'tier' of hit rating is worth less than the previous.

Comment: I suppose if Assassination didn't get so much of it's damage from poisons, the relative value for hit wouldn't be so low. I suspect Hit rating is superior for the other two specs (which, admittedly, are not what the question is asking about)

Comment: Nope. If anything, Hit is strongest for Assassination of the three specs. It's even worse for Combat and Subtlety, since both get much less damage out of poisons (which are based on the spell hit cap). While the value of Yellow Hit is higher for Combat/Sub, this is largely irrelevant. If you aren't yellow hit capped as a Rogue, you're probably wearing gear with Spirit on it -  which poses problems of it's own, not solvable with consumables.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you want to split your stats.
If you want to only concentrate on critical strikes, just buff Crit rating.
But buffing Agility will increase both crit and dodge at the same time, albeit at less rating than one of them by itself.

Refer to http://www.wowwiki.com/Attributes#Agility
It shows you the amount of Agility needed to achieve 1% of crit or dodge rating.

The way I see it, buffing haste only would mean "I can hit so fast, but I crit less often now".
Buffing crit only would mean "I can crit more often now, but I don't hit that fast anyway".

Comment: WoWwiki is outdated these days... (on mechanics articles at least)